# Rails Tutorial (M. Hartl) Chapter 8 Error: Undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Edited: Different error now, code posted still the same.

On chapter 8.3 of Hartl's Ruby Tutorial. Getting this error on the rake test for valid login test.

```
 test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1454541872.34s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `redirect_to_root_url' for #<SessionsController:0x007fce97a93068>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:39:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:39:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

The error message points to line 39 in my login test and line 18 in my Sessions controller as the errors, as you can see here:

```
test/integration/users_login_test.rb:39:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
```

**users_login_test.rb:**

Line 39 would be 'delete logout_path'

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
        @user = users(:michael)
    end

    test "login with invalid information" do
        get login_path
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        assert_not flash.empty?
        get root_path
        assert flash.empty?
    end

  test "login with valid information" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template 'users/show'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    end

   test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

Tried my best to fix the relevant code. I think I have the destroy method defined properly and in the right place. Here is my sessions helper and controller.

**sessions_controller.rb:**

Line 18 would be 'redirect_to_root_url'

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController


 def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to_root_url
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb:**

```
module SessionsHelper

    #Logs in the given user.
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    #Returns the current logged in user, if any
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    #Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise
    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    #Logs out current user
    def log_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end
end
```

Comment: Which section and subsection of the chapter are you in?

Comment: Section 8.3 Logging Out, Listing 8.28 is right where I'm stuck

Comment: Edited, the error is different now, not sure why but maybe it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sessions_controller.rb` file change:

```
def destroy
  log_out
  redirect_to_root_url
end
```

to

```
def destroy
  log_out
  redirect_to root_url
end
```